# Can rspec test a view to make sure view syntax/helpers don't have errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Using rspec, is it possible to test a view to make sure all the syntax in the view doesn't have any errors?

Views call helpers, they might reference controller/action names like controller => 'blah', action => 'show' etc.

If I rename/delete a controller I want to make sure that if my views reference them, I have a test that will fail.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) I wouldn't recommend using `:controller` or `:action` anywhere in your views, because RESTful helpers are much shorter. For instance:

```
:controller => :projects, :action => "show", :id => 1
```

vs.

```
project_path(1)
```

2) Rather than testing for syntax errors this way, have proper integration tests which test your application, performing the same actions a user would. Commonly, this is provided by RSpec+Capybara or Cucumber.

---

Now that we have the formalities out of the way, you can change the `describe` of your controller tests to this:

```
 describe ProjectsController
   render_views
```

By default, views in RSpec controller tests are stubbed out, meaning they are not accessed *at all*. By putting `render_views` inside your `describe` (or `context`) blocks, you enable this option.